# create list from a list if matching using jinja

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

simple ansible playbook is described below:

we want to filter the `accounts` from matching `filtered_accounts`. for simplicity have given the values as a single list, but it is actually a map of list.

```
---

- name: my playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    accounts: ["1111111111","2222222222","3333333333","4444444444"]
    filter_account: ["1111111111","3333333333"]
  tasks:

    - name: "Generate KMS policy to allow access for all Organisation child accounts"
      template:
        src: "data-kms-policy.json.j2"
        dest: "data-kms-policy.json"
      tags: gk

    - name: "cat kms json file"
      shell: "cat data-kms-policy.json"
      register: result
      tags: gk
```

data-kms-policy.json.j2:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow cross-account use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "AWS": [{% for host in accounts %}{% if host in filter_account and not loop.last %}"arn:aws:iam::{{ host }}:root",{% endif %}{% if host in filter_account and loop.last %}"arn:aws:iam::{{ host }}:root"{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
         },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
]}
```

expected output:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow cross-account use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root","arn:aws:iam::3333333333:root"]
         },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }]}
```

actual output:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow cross-account use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root","arn:aws:iam::3333333333:root", ]
         },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }]}
```

the issue with current data-kms-policy.json.j2 is it is appending "," at the end of last element always, how to remove that "," if it is the last matching element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely enjoy not having so much copy-pasta by moving that `if host in` clause up into the `for` loop, and then extracting the delimiter test

```
- debug:
    msg: |
       "AWS": [
          {%- for host in accounts if host in filter_account -%}
          {{ "" if loop.first else "," }}
          "arn:aws:iam::{{ host }}:root"
          {%- endfor -%}
       ]
```

Ordinarily I would also strongly recommend using `| to_json` to construct JSON formatted data, since it gets one out of the "is this legal JSON" business, but in this case the risk is pretty low and the `list` construction code is pretty verbose due to the need for the `format`